# Insertar en un método un bucle con try catch

Tags: java, try-catch, metodos

Estoy intentando que esté método al que le introduzco un mensaje como parámetro me devuelva un entero positivo, además tengo que usar un try-catch para que me lo pregunte hasta que inserte un valor correcto. Me da error al meter el return dentro del try.

```
public static int enteroPositivo(String mensaje){
    int entero = 0;
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println(mensaje);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            entero = scan.nextInt();
            return entero;
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Por favor, introduzca un valor correcto.");
        }
    }while (entero>0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que tu método regresa un entero, no puedes dejar el `return` únicamente dentro del `try/catch`

Supongamos que tienes la siguiente función

```
public static int dividir(int a, int b) {
    try {
        return a/b;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No puedes dividir entre 0");
    }
}
```

Y luego ingresamos hacemos lo siguiente.

```
int divison = dividir(0,0)
```

Puedes notar que tu función `dividir` no va detener el programa aunque falle, para eso es el `try/catch`. Sin embargo al momento de usarlo y asignarlo a un `int` no le asignará uni `int` pues nunca llego a un `return`

En resumen no puedes decir que tu función regresará un `int` porque estás mintiendo, pudiste ver en el ejemplo anterior que no siempre lo regresa.

Hablando de tu ejemplo en particular ahora, es claro que obligas a tu programa a regresar un `int` pues no sales del ciclo hasta que lo haga. pero para el compilador sigue siendo obligatorio que tu función sí o sí, regrese un `int`

Por lo tanto basta con regresar un `int` fuera del `try/catch`

```
public static int enteroPositivo(String mensaje){
    int entero = 0;
    do{
        try{
            System.out.println(mensaje);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            entero = scan.nextInt();
            return entero;
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Por favor, introduzca un valor correcto.");
        }
    }while (entero>0);
    return entero;
}
```

Puedes leer [este artículo](http://javafoundations.blogspot.com/2011/08/return-statement-vs-try-catch.html) si te quedaron dudas.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo he podido solucionar! También me he dado cuenta de que el while debía tener (entero<0), en lugar de (entero>0), ya que si no siempre iba a devolver el valor, aunque sea negativo.